# World machine outputs terraced maps (minecraft)

Tags: maya

[image]

As you can see on the image above, when displacement map was applied to a plane it gave me this Minecraft look, while it should look smth like that

[image]

Same goes for Maya, when i add same height map in Maya, it produces the exact same result.

the height map it self also looks terraced when zoomed in and probably this is what causing this effect, but i added same height map to unreal engine Landscape and it produced awesome results without any terracing.

Somebody please help me. SOS

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> the height map it self also looks terraced when zoomed in and probably this is what causing this effect

You've answered your own question.

Sounds like you need to carefully blur to remove the terracing - maybe apply a high-pass to keep some of your higher-frequency data, and re-apply that after you've used blur to de-terrace.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well 2d height map could look terraced due to 8 bit monitor right :)